# My Candy Apple is too brittle, how to prevent?

Tags: candy, texture, apples

I am cooking the candy mixture to 302°F and dipping right away, but the candy seems to be brittle and not holding to the apple when you either cut into it or try and bite into it.

*How can I prevent this?*

I am using the following ingredients:

- 3 cups sugar
- 1 cup water
- 1/2 cup light corn syrup
- 1 teaspoon vanilla extract
- White food coloring
- 2 additional colors of food coloring (I made marble apples)

Comment: I'm not a candy maker, but have you calibrated your thermometer recently?  It might be reading a few degrees low.  Also, depending on where you get your apples from, they might be waxed, so make sure to clean (and dry) them well.  (see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/65274/67 )

Comment: I have washed all off the bee's wax off of the apples as well as calibrated the thermometers(I use two just in case one is wrong). I am going to make another batch today and test them out. I know the humidity can affect the candy so I am going to try bagging immediately after cooling. Not sure if this will help.

Comment: **@Luciano** Please review [my edits](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/34942/fabby) as there is a difference between a [Candy apple](https://www.joyofkosher.com/.image/c_limit%2Ccs_srgb%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto:good%2Cw_860/MTM5NzU0Mjk4NDAwNTgwNjE4/bigstock-isolated-toffee-apple-8223264jpg.jpg) and [Apple candy](https://www.groovycandies.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/363x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/a/p/appleheads_candy.jpg)  **;-) 0:-)**

Comment: what altitude do you live at?

Comment: Maybe you want soft-crack instead of hard-crack... Try around 290F

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, maybe you should try for Soft Crack instead of hard crack.

If you are unable to rely on the thermometer just try a cold water test. Drop some hot candy in to iced water. Stop cooking after the hard ball stage. As soon as it will form pliable threads.
See

- https://www.instructables.com/id/Candy-Making-without-a-Thermometer-Cold-Water-Tes/
- https://www.thespruceeats.com/making-candy-without-a-candy-thermometer-520309

These tests show what happens as the candy cools, and so predict what the final candy will be like. Even if your mix needs a different temperature from the 302 F you are aiming for it should work.
Make a note of what the indicated temperature is on your thermometer, and if the candy apples are ok then on future batches just use that thermometer and that temperature.