# Does washing an apple with cool water remove most of the wax and residue?

Tags: cleaning, apples

[Livestrong](https://www.livestrong.com/article/449504-is-apple-peel-good-for-you/):

> You'll remove most of the wax and residue by rinsing the apple under cool water

Is this true?

Ideally, I'd like for some actual scientific research that compares various methods for washing/cleaning apples.

Comment: You trimmed down the advice: "You'll remove most of the wax and residue by rinsing the apple under cool water and drying it with a clean towel or paper towel. If needed, rub it gently with a soft cloth or vegetable brush to scrub away the wax."  I suspect it's like washing your hands, where water temperature isn't as significant as the rubbing

Comment: Related, and maybe should be considered duplicate: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32162, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/65274/, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25217

Comment: I agree with Joe, the only thing removing wax with this method is the advice to rub which you omitted. Wax isn't water soluble so cold water will have no effect but hot water would melt it.